# Draggable element in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop, draggable

If I want to make a div draggable I have to specify a reference parent or not?For example in jquery,when an element is draggable does it have a reference parent?

Comment: you just need to add the `draggable` attrib to the element, not sure what parents have to do with it...

Answer (score 3):

To drag an element, you just need to add the `draggable` attribute and set it's value equal to `true`.

This will not work on ancient browsers such as Internet Explorer 8 or earlier, because the `draggable` attribute was nor supported by them.

What you are probably thinking of is a drop target. By default, elements may not be dropped inside other elements.

It's important to note that the following dragging events require an `event` parameter.

- **ondrag**: Event is fired whenever an element is being dragged
- **ondragstart** - Event is fired when the dragging process is started
- **ondragend** - Event is fired when the dragging process is finished
- **ondragenter** - Event is fired when the dragged element enters a drop target
- **ondragleave** - Event is fired when the dragged element leaves a drop target
- **ondragover** - Event is fired when the dragged element is over a drop target

To allow a drop, we must change the default behavior of browsers through `event.preventDefault`.

This example is courtesy of W3Schools. However, it is explains the drag and drop functionality. Unfortunately, there are no `pseudo classes` for dragging and dropping events so we need to use native JavaScript.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_ondragstart.asp

```js
var demo = document.getElementById("demo");

// Use dataTransfer.setData() to set data type and value of dragged data
// When dragging starts, the paragraph will output text and opacity will decrease
document.addEventListener("dragstart", function(event) {
    event.dataTransfer.setData("Text", event.target.id);
    demo.innerHTML = "Started to drag the p element.";
    event.target.style.opacity = "0.4";
});

document.addEventListener("drag", function(event) {
    demo.style.color = "red";                    // Change color of output text
});

// Output some text when finished dragging the p element and reset the opacity
document.addEventListener("dragend", function(event) {
    demo.innerHTML = "Finished dragging the p element.";
    event.target.style.opacity = "1";
});


/* Events fired on the drop target */

// When the draggable p element enters the droptarget, change the DIVS's border style
document.addEventListener("dragenter", function(event) {
    if ( event.target.className == "droptarget" ) {
        event.target.style.border = "3px dotted red";
    }
});

// By default, data/elements cannot be dropped in other elements. To allow a drop, we must prevent the default handling of the element
document.addEventListener("dragover", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});

// When the draggable p element leaves the droptarget, reset the DIVS's border style
document.addEventListener("dragleave", function(event) {
    if ( event.target.className == "droptarget" ) {
        event.target.style.border = "";
    }
});

/* On drop - Prevent the browser default handling of the data (default is open as link on drop)
   Reset the color of the output text and DIV's border color
   Get the dragged data with the dataTransfer.getData() method
   The dragged data is the id of the dragged element ("drag1")
   Append the dragged element into the drop element
*/
document.addEventListener("drop", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ( event.target.className == "droptarget" ) {
        demo.style.color = "";
        event.target.style.border = "";
        var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
        event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }
});
```

```css
.droptarget {
    float: left; 
    width: 100px; 
    height: 35px;
    margin: 15px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
```

```html
<p>Drag the p element back and forth between the two rectangles:</p>

<div class="droptarget">
  <p draggable="true" id="dragtarget">Drag me!</p>
</div>

<div class="droptarget"></div>

<p style="clear:both;"><strong>Note:</strong> drag events are not supported in Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions or Safari 5.1 and earlier versions.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: I updated the post. Also, if you are using an ancient browser, it won't work. What browser were you using?

Comment: Thank you so much for answare:):)What I wanted to know is if a draggable element needs a reference parent to move itself.If I have a div father and a div son and I make son draggable,it will be draggable only inside his father or it will be draggable in all the window?